.NET Core Web API to a remote WCF ASP.NET Framework net.tcp service
I have an .NET Core 6 Web API (Service 1) that consumes an older WCF ASP.NET Framework 4.5.2 (Service 2) which runs over only over net.tcp. The second service has a database connection which reads and writes certain data.
I am able to use the connected services feature in Visual Studio which adds the service references from Service 2 into Service 1. I have a simple test endpoint in Service 2 which has no database connection and responds fine. However, when using a resource that has a database connection using integrated security, from Service 1, I get an unusual error:

outer exception - Authentication Failed.
inner exception - Target principal name is incorrect.

I am not 100% sure but I believe this suffers from the notorious Windows two hop delegation scenario. I have seen it before many years ago but not quite sure how to remedy it with an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API (Service 1).
On Service 2, I found that using the standard WCF Client app works as expected. It is only when I use it through Service 1 do I experience this this issue. I do not have much liberty to change Service 2, the legacy app - but I can change Service 1. Does anyone have any configuration/code setup on how I would achieve this?
There is a lot of information on WCF and ASP.NET core but I am not sure I have seen this scenario in any of the documentation. I am open to ideas or suggestions on the best approach to this problem

make sure you have set up the SPN for both of the services.  In Active Directory, configure the service account for Service 1 to allow delegation to the service account of Service 2.coud you share your windows auth code?try to use tool like klist to check the Kerberos tickets on the client machine.
